# Can I use "always" in front of any prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositions

> A youth always in love

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-love

Can I use "always" in front of any prepositional phrase?

e.g. A man always in a white suit

Comment: The intensifier / adverb of frequency ***always*** won't usually work very well unless preceded by a relative pronoun. *A youth **who is** always in love, A building **which is** always occupied, Answers **that are** always welcome...*

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can, but keep in mind that "A youth always in love" is not a complete sentence as it lacks a verb; It is called a sentence fragment and does not convey a complete thought.