# Can I use "still" directly without verbs?

Tags: word-usage, prepositional-phrases

> The radiant smile and the sparkle in her blue eyes were the clear
> signs of **a woman still deeply in love**.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deeply

"A woman still deeply in love". Is it grammatical without "which is" as in "a woman which is still deeply in love"?

If so, can I use "still" in front of any prepositional phrase?

e.g.

1. He is **a man still in short pants.**
2. She is **a woman still in need of food.**

Comment: Because _she_ is a person (and not a thing) we would say 'a woman **who** is still deeply in love', and, yes, you can omit 'who is' in both of your examples and similar sentences.

Comment: Not *any* PP, at least not without a very strained and unnatural example.  *A cup still of water.  *A stitch still in time.  *A meal eaten still with gusto.  *A man who had fallen still off the wagon.

Comment: *I received a letter still from him.  *It was Santa Claus still after all.

Comment: I think _still_ can precede an adjunct, but not a complement.

Comment: @TimR - 'A man who had fallen still off the wagon' sounds like he was dead already.

Comment: The OP has asked the same question about "always": https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346039/can-i-use-always-in-front-of-any-prepositional-phrase

Answer (score 1):

These sentences are examples of [whiz-deletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiz_deletion#:%7E:text=In%20linguistics%2C%20whiz%20deletion%20is,to%20be%E2%80%9D%20are%20both%20deleted.), where "who is" has been omitted. If you have a sentence that contains a relative pronoun (who, which, that) followed by a be-verb, you can omit them.

> ... a woman [who is] still deeply in love.
> He is a man [who is] still in short pants.
> She is a woman [who is] still in need of food.

There is nothing special about 'still': you can do it with any sentence containing wh- and is/are/was/were:

> He sat on a carpet [that was] frayed at the edges and covered with stains.

Answer (score 0):

> The radiant smile and the sparkle in her blue eyes were the clear signs of **a woman still deeply in love**.

The verb of the sentence is *were*.

*the clear signs of a woman still deeply in love* is the subject complement.  Within it, *a woman still deeply in love* is the object of preposition *of*.  It is a valid noun phrase.  (We can also use *a woman **who** is still deeply in love*, but that's unnecessary; the *who is* can be omitted, by whiz-deletion.)  The adverb *still* modifies another adverb *deeply*.  This is a valid use of an adverb.

Using *still* to modify the prepositional phrases *in short pants* and *in need of food* in your examples is fine, but this does not apply to all prepositional phrases, as @TimR commented.